# Complex integral for the power series expansion

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Find the radius of convergence of the power series expansion of the function
$$f(z) = \frac{e^{z^2}}{z(z − 1)(z − 2)^2}$$ at $z_{0} = i + 1$

The question asks me to find the radius of convergence without getting power series expansion.

My approach:

Since I know that from Cauchy integral theorem, f(z) = $a_{n}(z-z_{0})^n$ where $a_{n} = f^{n}(z_{0})/n!$ and I also tried to use the fact that $e^{z^2}$ power series expansion, but it looks like this was not allowed. Also since I know $z_{0}$, does this mean i + 1 is the radius of convergence?

Comment: You don't need to find the coefficients $s_n$ to do this ....

Comment: There are singularities at $z=0,1,2$ and the closest one to $z_0=1+i$ is $z=1$ so the radius of convergence has to be $R=|(1+i)-1|=1$.

Comment: @PeterForeman, oh. so this question revolves around singularities. Thanks!

Comment: @PeterForeman, isn't radius of convergence supposed to i instead of 1?

Comment: The radius of convergence is a non-negative real number. As I wrote in my previous answer it is given by the distance between the complex numbers $1+i$ and $1$ which is $|(1+i)-1|=|i|=1$.